# Necesito ayuda con una función para llenar una tabla pivot con el attach

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, vue.js

Estoy intentando llenar una tabla pivot, en la cual requiero dos datos de una de las tablas que están relacionadas la relación es de persona a horarios y debo asignar un horario a una persona. De la tabla horario necesito la hora de entrada y hora de salida pero a la hora de asignar me arroja error interno de la función.

Esta es la funcion que quiero ejecutar

```
 public function savePeopleSchedule($listSchedule,$people) 
{
    $this->schedule->save();

    foreach ($listSchedule as $schedule){
        $people->schedule()->attach(
            $schedule['id'],
            $schedule['ArrivalTime'],
            $schedule['departureTime'],
            ['state_id' => 1]
        );
```

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PeopleController::savePeopleSchedule(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected